# Unable to run a PyTorch model (IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I created a PyTorch model and trained it. It's a very simple neural network:

```py
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(NUM_RANDOMS, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, MAX_NUM_OUTPUT),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return logits
```

After training, however, when I try to run it with the following code:

```
model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
  print(model(corpus_train.dataset[0][0]))
```

where `corpus_train` represents the `DataLoader` used for training, I keep getting the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-73e4e7e0a291> in <cell line: 4>()
      3 with torch.no_grad():
----> 4   print(model(corpus_test.dataset[0][0]))

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

The input to the model is supposed to be a 1d tensor with 16 elements, and the output will then be 1728 element long tensor.

EDIT:

`corpus_train` and `corpus_test` are defined in the same way:

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

split_idx = (99*len(corpus))//100

corpus_train_dataset = CorpusDataset(corpus[:split_idx])
corpus_test_dataset = CorpusDataset(corpus[split_idx:])

corpus_train = DataLoader(corpus_train_dataset)
corpus_test = DataLoader(corpus_test_dataset)
```

where `corpus` is a long list of unique words. `CorpusDataset` is defined as:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch import tensor
import numpy as np

class CorpusDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, corpus):
    self.corpus = corpus

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.corpus)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    doc = self.corpus[idx]
    embedded = []
    for i in range(len(doc)):
      char = doc[i]
      embedded.extend(get_mapping(char))

    embedded = pad_embedding(embedded)

    random_tensor = tensor(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, NUM_RANDOMS), dtype=torch.float32)
    random_tensor = random_tensor.to(device)

    embedded_tensor = tensor(embedded, dtype=torch.float32)
    embedded_tensor = embedded_tensor.to(device)

    return [random_tensor, embedded_tensor]
```

The `get_mapping` function simply takes in a character and returns a list where the ith element (i being the index of the character in the abcd sequence) is 1.

`pad_embedding` takes in a list of flattened mappings and just adds a bunch of zeroes to make it a specific length.

`NUM_RANDOMS` is equal to `16`
`MAX_NUM_OUTPUT` is equal to `1728`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```py
    print(model(next(iter(corpus_train.dataset))[0]))
```

see https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#iterate-through-the-dataloader

Comment: Hmm... Nope, same error again

Comment: Can we see where your `corpus_train` is defined?

Comment: Sure! I updated the question with the relevant code